# Use one type in multiple parts of a Nest.js controller method

Tags: typescript, nestjs, decorator

I have a system of sharing types between the backend in frontend which looks something like this in the controller:

```
@Controller()
export class MyController {
  
  @ApplyRoute('GET /foo')
  async findAll(
    @Query() { name }: Routes['GET /foo']['query'], // repeated route name
  ): Promise<Routes['GET /foo']['response']> { // repeated route name
    return { foo: true }
  }
}
```

Note how 'GET /foo' appears 3 times: once to declare the http method/path, once to get the type of query parameters, and once to enforce the return type.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQzGANgTwCIFMDG0yM0AzgDRwBKuAjgK66kwCyqYwAdgOaU0NNWuGAAsIAE0oBhCJxhQI6dLiiUAioyiY4AXzgAzBSDgByAAKdBAK1IB6QiBCyTAKBcxMYXNQj0YTOABeRBc4UwBxAFEAFThbfQgIEwAuELCwgS1UpE5kEFxU5igubl1Q9KgmSE5SAsQDRNT5RjKwnTcwkyjY2wAjZCgUtPTMzGydcnKwytJq2uy4fqgmqBb2tpd2l1wAD0hYA3pOfBhgWTgAQTQsKl9-AAoFP1wAOTy6gGtcTAh9H2fSABKVIsYRicR4QhQYjQYaEGrwADa+VEEkoYGIIgAukE4E9-G98gA6WboYAwe4mUyAlCkOCIroxKkAH1MAAUAPIAZWiJkoRRKWPKlRg9CgnBQ1xwBCIJCgpHuU2odEYzDYaBK9yQGNElBR4NS-FVQlR4mRYIkOJ0gMmYUBmzcZhkcgUShU93tu328Hw6GQpDpLEwzvkimUUGG5TMVwwmFuz0p3TiCSS9rC-swxwMXHEFyUivScDMGhUmA99Vy+V0hruTAZSfiiRMWIZo2blFstjxuC8xFw4jxtbgldw5WBcDZRmAtQAPPH-KR6zFk02WyYZnNcM2AHz1Tvd3v+Af47wjpUisUSpAplZrcrtHRAA)

I'm looking for a way to somehow remove that repetition, but I can't seem to think of any way that plays nice with the decorators. Right now someone could use the path of one route and then use a different route's `query` or `response`, which is probably quite wrong.

How can this duplication of route names be removed?

---

For example, something that does what this totally invalid syntax implies:

```
@Controller()
export class MyController {
  
  @ApplyRoute('GET /foo') {
    async findAll(
      @Query() { name }: CurrentRoute['query'],
    ): Promise<CurrentRoute['response']> {
      return { foo: true }
    }
  }
}
```

---

For additional info, the plumbing works like this.

There is a type that defines all routes, and the types that route accepts and returns:

```
type Routes = {
  'GET /foo': {
    query: { name: string }
    response: { foo: true }
  }

  'GET /bar': {
    query: {},
    response: { bar: true }
  }
}
```

Then we have a little helper decorator which parses the route name to the `@RequestMapping()` decorator to set the http method and path for a controller method:

```
export function ApplyRoute(routeName: keyof Routes): MethodDecorator {
  const [method, path] = routeName.split(' ') as ['GET' | 'POST', string]
  return applyDecorators(
    RequestMapping({ path, method: RequestMethod[method] }),
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the [dynamic routing](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1438) techniques to remove the code duplication. Consider this example:

```js
// define a controller that will host all methods of `Routes`
// it's, of course, also possible to have many of these or even have them generated based on the `Routes` descriptor
@Controller()
export class MyController {}

function Action<T extends keyof Routes>(route: T, fn: (query: Routes[T]["query"]) => Routes[T]["response"]): void {
  const [method, path] = route.split(" ") as ["GET" | "POST", string];
  const key = path.split("/").join("_");

  // assigning the function body to a method in the controller class
  MyController.prototype[key] = fn;

  // applying the `Query` directive to the first parameter
  // this could also be configured through the `Routes` in case if you have e.g. post methods
  Query()(MyController.prototype, key, 0);

  // applying the `Get` decorator to the controller method
  RequestMapping({ path: path, method: RequestMethod[method] })(
    MyController,
    key,
    Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyController.prototype, key)
  );
}

// now, register the methods in the global scope
Action("GET /foo", ({ name: string }) => ({ foo: true }));
Action("GET /bar", () => ({ bar: true }));
```

Comment: I don't think this will play nice with Swagger or Typescript, but it's a start. It does feel like NestJS is lacking some dynamic routing features that would make this a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [decorators cannot mutate a class definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9453#issuecomment-361407365) [and there's a lot of issues in the Typescript repo about decorators not being able to modify classesor their definitions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881). This includes the type definition to my understanding, so there's no immediate way to say that when a method has a decorator that a different type should be the return. The closest you could get, taking your contrived example, would be to rename the `Routes['GET /foo']` to a type alias like `type FooRoute = Routes['Get /foo']` so that you now only need `FooRoute['query']`.

```js
// contrived example from original post, modified

import { applyDecorators, RequestMapping, RequestMethod, Controller, Query } from '@nestjs/common'

type Routes = {
  'GET /foo': {
    query: { name: string }
    response: { foo: true }
  }

  'GET /bar': {
    query: {},
    response: { bar: true }
  }
}

export function ApplyRoute(routeName: keyof Routes): MethodDecorator {
  const [method, path] = routeName.split(' ') as ['GET' | 'POST', string]
  return applyDecorators(
    RequestMapping({ path, method: RequestMethod[method] }),
  )
}

type FooRoute = Routes['GET /foo']

@Controller()
export class MyController {
  
  @ApplyRoute('GET /foo')
  async findAll(
    @Query() { name }: FooRoute['query'], // repeated route name
  ): Promise<FooRoute['response']> { // repeated route name
    return { foo: true }
  }
}
```

So now there's *less* repeated code, but it is still repeated in the end.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't good enough. I am open to alternatives, though, like may some fancy inheritance or something. Or building a method one at a time and attaching it to the controller prototype. But I just can't wrap my head around how that might work with decorators. Maybe because this just isn't possible, though.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see what the draw of doing something like this would be. You hinder Nest's ability to read the type metadata because you are using types instead of classes so the `ValidaitonPIpe` won't be usable, and any swagger metadata won't be applicable either unless you manually type all of that out too. Like I said in my first statement, decorators cannot modify the types of a method, so the only way you could even start to get _close_ to this would be a large, unwieldy mixin that once it works you'll probably never want to make changes to.